# Estimating commutator of Fourier integral

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f(x)= \log(\vert x\vert)$ on $\mathbb R^2$ and define $s_n:H^2 \to L^2$ where $H^2$ is the second Sobolev space by

$$ s_n(g)(x) =  \frac{nf(x)}{4\pi i} \int_{\mathbb R^2} e^{\frac{in\vert x-y\vert^2}{4}} g(y) \ dy -  \frac{n}{4\pi i} \int_{\mathbb R^2} e^{\frac{in\vert x-y\vert^2}{4}} f(y)g(y) \ dy,$$
where the integral operator is the kernel describing $e^{i\Delta/n}$ such that
$$ s_n(g) = [f,e^{i/n\Delta}]g.$$

I am interested in understanding the scaling of the operator norm of this commutator operator $s_n$.

Intuitively, we have for $n \to \infty$ that the limiting operator is
$$s_{\infty}(g)(x) = f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(x)=0.$$

So we expect the operator norm to go to zero, I would like to know: What is the rate in $n$?